# Handling enum changes in Entity Framework 5

Tags: .net, entity-framework, enums, migration, entity-framework-5

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909537/does-the-new-migrations-feature-of-entity-framework-5-fully-support-enum-changes/11941863#11941863), I discovered that enum changes are not handled by Entity Framework migrations. In fact, enum changes don't even result in a model changed error, so you can change enums at will with no controls.

Enum changes that result in different int values, such as order changes or removals, can effectively render the database data invalid, since the meaning of the stored integer is now wrong.

In order for Migrations to work, you have to manually execute custom SQL that changes the changed enum values.

The problem is, the developer has to remember to do this, and if there was an oversight then effective data corruption can occur.

How can someone put into place checks against this? Is it possible to, in the event an enum changes, throw a model change error or something like this?

Comment: The same question applies for renames: If someone forgets to treat the specially the old column will be dropped and a new one created. Auto-migrations are unsuitable for production use if downtime is a concern.

Comment: As no model change is required for new enums, no model change error would be thrown. EF has no way of knowing that enum value '1' in the  database is different from 'Car' which had that value but since renamed to 'truck', enums are generally considered constants and shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Well there is ContextKey - a fully qualified type name - and a Model - which is some kind of binary blob in __MigrationHistory table. That blob should contain the Enum definition and detect this kind of changes. Apparently It doesn't. This looks like a bad design of EF.

Answer (score 2):

A similar problem with enums exists in .Net when you move them out to a different Project to be used as a library:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/271483-q-why-casting-enum#post1086722

Try it - enums in general are surprisingly brittle. The answer is to always assign an explicit value to your enums, to prevent both problems. This allows you to still leverage their core value (clear names instead of magic numbers and a little more to type safety in method arguments), but prevents you from quietly breaking everything.

You can enforce this policy with code reviews or post-commit hooks via a regex.